# Building a flat calendar using D3.js

Tags: d3.js

Unable to follow what these numbers mean in the code fragment. The source code is available in the [link](http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173)

```
if ((maxExtent - minExtent) > **1468800000**) {
        x1DateAxis.ticks(d3.time.mondays, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d'))
        x1MonthAxis.ticks(d3.time.mondays, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b - Week %W'))        
    }
    else if ((maxExtent - minExtent) > **172800000**) {
        x1DateAxis.ticks(d3.time.days, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d'))
        x1MonthAxis.ticks(d3.time.mondays, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b - Week %W'))
    }
    else {
        x1DateAxis.ticks(d3.time.hours, 4).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%I %p'))
        x1MonthAxis.ticks(d3.time.days, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %e'))
    }
```

Comment: Time is often measured in 'epoch' format for calculation purposes, defined as the number of seconds from 00:00:00 Jan 1 1970 (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). If it were my code I would define those 'magic' numbers as constants to explain what they were (i.e. SECONDS_IN_2_DAYS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is specifying the intervals at which tick (unit) marks will be placed on a dateline/axis, and the format of the label that will go with each tick mark.  The longer the period represented by the line, the coarser the granularity of the ticks on that line will be.

1468800000 is the number of milliseconds in 17 days, 172800000 is the number of milliseconds in 2 days.  So a dateline that spans less than 2 days, a dateline that spans between 2 and 17 days, and a dateline that spans more than 17 days will get different tick intervals and labels.  (Well, in this specific case the labels for 2-17 days and >17 days will be in the same format, but the ticks will be at different intervals.)